# Getting urls out of block of text?

Tags: python, regex, url

I have a large chunk of text and would like to parse out all the URLs, returning a list of the urls that follow this pattern: https://www.facebook.com/.*$.

Here is an example of the text I would like to parse from:

```
<abbr title="Monday xxxx" data-utime="xx" class="timestamp">over a year ago</abbr></div></div></div></div></div></li><li class="fbProfileBrowserListItem"><div class="clearfix _5qo4"><a class="_8o _8t lfloat" href="https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx?fref=pb&amp;hc_location=profile_browser" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=xxxx&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22profile_browser%22%7D"><img class="_s0 _rw img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-xxxxxxxx.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/xxxxxx.jpg" alt=""></a><div class="clearfix _42ef"><div class="_6a rfloat"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:50px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="_5t4x"><div class="FriendButton" id="u_2h_1w"><button class="_42ft _4jy0 FriendRequestAdd addButton _4jy3 _517h" type="button">
```

And I would like to get "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx?fref=pb&hc_location=profile_browser"

**What I tried**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = open('full_page_firefox.html')
def getLinks(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    anchors = soup.findAll('a')
    links = []
    for a in anchors:
        links.append(a['href'])
    return links
print getLinks(html)
```

Splitting also doesn't seem to work because it does not retain the pattern. So if I use something like "https://www.facebook.com/*.$" to get the urls with re.split() or something, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hope this blog post might be useful to somebody regarding this. http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/08/web-scraping-beginner-python.html

Answer (score 1):

your code works here, check your input file, make sure beautiful soap can parse it.

btw, also consider using a lxml

```
from lxml import etree
print etree.parse('full_page_firefox.html').xpath('//a/@href | //img/@src')

['https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx?fref=pb&hc_location=profile_browser', 
'https://fbcdn-profile-xxxxxxxx.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/xxxxxx.jpg']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function works. I copied the bit of html you provided into a html file and added the `<html>` and `<body>` tags for good measure.

Then I tried:

```
with open('C:/users/brian/desktop/html.html') as html:
    print getLinks(html)
```

in the python interpreter and got the following output:

```
[u'https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx?fref=pb&hc_location=profile_browser']
```

call `str` on this and you're good

Answer (score 1):

you can check the url by that pattern, after parsed by BS, like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = open('full_page_firefox.html')
def getLinks(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    anchors = soup.findAll('a')
    links = []
    for a in anchors:
        match_result = re.match(r'https://www.facebook.com/.*$', a['href'])
        if match_result is not None:
            links.append(match_result.string)
    return links
print getLinks(html)
```

Note:
1.no whitespace between '/' and '.'
2.'$' match end of string, careful to use